# convert time string to integer mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following string format stored in my mysql database,

```
     starttime
    8:00 31-5-2012
```

I want to convert it into integer to compare with another integer like 1338447620

can anyone help me, any help will be grately appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you can store it as a mysql-datetime, you simply could use

```
select unix_timestamp(starttime);
```

Datetime has a lot more pro's, you can sort and calculate with it. Just read it with date_format, and you get your local timeformat. So I suggest: convert it to datetime in the database.